# Use a cluster ConfigMap value as a conditional check in a Helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster and an application that I am trying to deploy on it using Helm. The template file that I am making changes to is the `_helpers.tpl` file.

There's a certain ConfigMap value that my cluster **doesn't have** (let `API_FLAG`), that my application needs to run an *optional job* (let's say `publishapi`, set `true` by default) defined in the `Values.yaml` file. There are also other ConfigMap values that need to be present for the job to finish successfully, which I can then further add to the check case.

I need to create a certain workflow that basically checks that :

- if `API_FLAG` is present in our cluster, then other ConfigMap values are validated and `publishapi` proceeds as default (`true`), but
- if `API_FLAG` is not present in my cluster, then the whole `publishapi` step must not run, i.e., act like it was set `false`,
- and also throw no errors in either cases.

I know how to use and call ConfigMap values, but I am unable to use conditionals *with* ConfiMap values as checks. A simple code snippet to explain this problem and what I am trying could be:

```
if (env.API_FLAG) {
    // get other ConfigMap values/secrets from the environment
    // set Values.publishapi -> true
} else {
    // set Values.publishapi -> false
}
```

So far the only documentation I've seen for this template only takes into account getting variables from Values.yaml files, but I can't get any documentation for getting ConfigMap values from a kubernetes cluster itself, without throwing any errors.

Some links for further reading :

- https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/
- https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/
- https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/templates/
- https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/

Comment: `helm` rendering happens on your local workstation, it does not happen cluster side so you can not make runtime conditionals in the template like this.

Comment: @jordanm ouch that hurts. So is there no way to get this environment variable check to be implemented?

Comment: I am pretty certain this is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There is no way to do this via helm the way that you are trying, but there are likely other ways to accomplish your goals. How is `Values.publishapi` used? Just to decide whether or not to create a `Job` resource?

Comment: @jordanm yes obviously. `Values.publishapi` has its own set of kubernetes jobs that are only run when its set as true, otherwise they don't execute when its set as false/commented out.

Comment: next question is, why are you trying to use env variable and not just put `publishapi = false` the values file (or `--set publishapi=false`) for the cluster in which you don't want the feature available?

Comment: @jordanm this was actually my first approach to this problem. But apparently the project I am working for has these env variables already present for later cluster versions. The older clusters don't have these variables. Consider this as a hotfix for legacy clusters, which we will not be using to publish our api, but this flag should check that _if_ that env variable is present, it should automatically adjust our `Values.publishapi` as either true or false. Publishing our api should be _optional_ on older clusters, and we can edit config map to add support for `API_FLAG`. Hope you understand..

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the clusters have env variables? What within the cluster has environment variables set? I am not aware of any concept of cluster-wide env variables in k8s. Is it actually just a ConfigMap or do you have some mutating webhook to inject the environment variable into resources?

Comment: @jordanm configmap values, not env variables, sorry. ConfigMap has these values. Late in the night, getting a coffee.

Comment: [flux](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/helmreleases/#refer-to-values-in-configmap-and-secret-resources) has this functionality to use a configmap as values to a helm install, but I am not aware of other tools that can do this. I don't think helm by itself can.

Comment: I guess I can take this up with the project lead then if we can use this utility to implement this functionality. This might not be the most optimal way, but atleast its a way.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes doesn't have any notion of "cluster variables" or "cluster environment variables".  Even questions like "what is the name of this cluster" have to be answered by injecting their values at deployment time.

In a Helm context, I'd address this by having a separate YAML values file per cluster.  This is separate from the `values.yaml` file that's part of your chart.  Then you can directly specify the variables you need there:

```yaml
# values.prod.yaml
apiFlag: true
publishapi: true
```

```yaml
# values.qa.yaml
apiFlag: false
publishapi: false
```

These can be checked into source control with the rest of your deployment infrastructure.  If you have multiple similar services, it could make sense to have one central copy of these files, or it could make sense to replicate them with each chart.

When you (or your deployment system) goes to deploy these, it needs to pass in the correct values file with a `helm install -f` option.

```bash
kubectl config use-context qa
helm upgrade my-chart . -f values.qa.yaml
...
kubectl config use-context prod
helm upgrade my-chart . -f values.prod.yaml
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I edited the question. By environment variables I meant the configmap values and secrets inside my cluster. it was a late night post, pulled a minor oopsie.

Comment: For the most part those can only be retrieved from the same namespace, so it's a little less helpful than it sounds.  The [`lookup`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) Helm template function might help here, though this could make it tricky to test a deployment in a local cluster (minikube, kind, Docker Desktop).